# "Shibboleet" Easter Egg for serverfault

Tags: feature-request

Would it be possible to add another Easter Egg to serverfault?

If so, we could use an easter egg that dumps anyone into chat if they type "Shibboleet" in a question.

It's obscure enough that it isn't likely to cause a problem for normal use and would be fun for the few who do know about it.

Based on xkcd.com/806
[image]

Comment: FYI: [tag:Shibboleth] is software somebody might ask about on SF and already has 15 questions with that tag...

Comment: When I saw "Shibboleet" I thought it must be some religious event and why would anyone ask a question about on SF. Anyway, have a -1 for suggesting that people get thrown into chat against their wishes.

Comment: I take your point and I'm not arguing the downvote @JohnGardeniers but I would point to the comic and suggest that anyone who intentionally types in 'Shibboleet' is wishing for *something* to happen.

Comment: @freiheit Good thing we're talking about Shibboleet.

Comment: @DJ, the reason I didn't read the whole comic is the same reason I no longer read xkcd at all. *Too many words* I like comics to be short and to the point, like Dilbert.

Comment: Looks interesting...

Answer (score 12):

Great idea. Just make sure that the user also automatically says "Shibboleet!" in chat and links the question.

Comment: Yep, it would need to do that as well I think